# Bootstrap has-danger for input-group not on separate lines as for form-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using an *input-group* gives some problems when using the style *has-danger* and adding help text and feedback fields. Using these on *form-group* separates them on each line, but using these on *input-group* places everything on the same line.

I have made a fiddle showing the problem when using *input-group* (top), the using *form-group* (middle) and trying to combine *form-group* and *input-group* (bottom).

[Here is a link to fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Bille88/6rgv9qau/1/)

Not working for input group. Feedback and help text should be on separated lines

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="form-group input-group has-danger">
   <label class="form-control-label" for="inputDanger1">Input with danger</label>
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" placeholder="Your email address" id="inputDanger1">
   <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken.</div>
   <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
    </div>
```

Working for form group. Feedback and help text should be on separated lines

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
<div class="form-group has-danger">
 <label class="form-control-label" for="inputDanger2">Input with danger</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" placeholder="Your email address" id="inputDanger2">
 <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken.</div>
 <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
</div>
```

Has-danger does not work when wrapping the input-group in a form-group

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div clas="form-group has-danger">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="inputDanger3">Input with danger</label>
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" placeholder="Your email address" id="inputDanger3">
  </div>
  <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken.</div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if I understood it correctly, but you wanted an input-group with has-danger? I tried this.  <div class="input-group has-danger"> in your fiddle and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the has-danger from here `<div class="form-group has-danger">`
And placed it here instead. `<div class="input-group">`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group ">
                <label class="form-control-label" for="inputDanger3">Input with danger</label>
                <div class="input-group has-danger"> 
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" placeholder="Your email address" id="inputDanger3">
                </div>
                <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken.</div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
              </div>
```

Adding back the has-danger in here `<div class="form-group has-danger">` will change the text to inherit the has-danger.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group has-danger">
                <label class="form-control-label" for="inputDanger3">Input with danger</label>
                <div class="input-group has-danger"> 
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" placeholder="Your email address" id="inputDanger3">
                </div>
                <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken.</div>
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
              </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I don't know why I hadn't tried that. However the _label_ and the _feedback_-text are still not red. How can that be?

Comment: form-control has its own font-color. you can try adding has-danger after it.  `class="form-control has-danger" ` and on `class="form-control-feedback has-danger"`, too.

Comment: I tested has-danger, but it can't override the form-controls. You have to edit form-control's color property to change it. but that will affect will other parts that uses the class.

Comment: But looking at the Bootstrap documentation, then the _has-danger_ class is just used on the _form-control_ and inherited: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#validation